# SSIS in Visual Studio 2012 - Package cannot read a project property from a file connection

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I have been searching for an answer and asked a couple of SSIS "gurus", but nobody seems to have a solution for my problem.

I have a main package which I use to load and execute child packages within my project. One of the child packages has a file connection (the input data file) which I can set from the parent. I point this connection to a dummy file, so I can have the input format defined at compile time. The connection string is defined in a variable:

User::inputFile = @[$Project::DATA_ROOT_DIR]+ @[$Project::SYS_NAME]+"\"+ @[$Project::ENV]+"\"+ @[$Project::SUB_SYS]+"\[filename]"

All project properties are defined to build the file path.

If I run the child package directly, it finishes all tasks without error, but when I call it from the parent (using Execute Package Task) I get:

Error   1   Error loading [Package].dtsx: The variable "$Project::DATA_ROOT_DIR" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope.

After this error I cannot run the child package directly anymore, since I keep getting the same error. This makes things even weirder. Furthermore, the error appears when the child package is loaded, it never gets to run.

Any ideas about what can be wrong?

Comment: This should be pretty easy to solve. Are you using the project deployment framework (new to 2012) or the package deployment (pre 2012 SSIS)? It looks like project deployment but I wanted to make sure. If so, are both packages in same project? Also, just a question - Why aren't you passing "User::INputFile" from the parent to the child as a $Package variable? Just curious

Comment: When you're mapping variables from the parent to the child, is your translation off from a casing perspective?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The problem does not appear when passing the variable, that works fine. The definition of the connection string is what generates the error, when the package is loaded.
It is a project deployment and all packages belong to the same project.